# Comparing means across levels of random effect in linear mixed effects model?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I'm running a study in which participants will rate various social groups using 2 scales. They'll also be asked to rate two statements about the groups that are presented to them. So, my IVs are as follows:

IV1 (continuous); IV2 (continuous); Statement (categorical, with 2 levels, a & b); Group (20 levels).

The DV is Statement-Rating.

My hypothesis is that there will be an interaction between IV1 and Statement, such that as ratings for IV1 increase, ratings for Statement(a) will increase, while ratings for Statement(b) will decrease.

To test this hypothesis, my plan is to run the following linear mixed effects model in R:

```r
lmer(StatementRating ~ 1 + IV1*IV2*Statement + 
                 (1 + IV1*IV2*Statement|Group) + 
                 (1 + IV1*IV2*Statement|Participant)
```

IV1, IV2, and Statement are within-subjects. I'm thinking of randomly assigning each participant to 4 groups (out of the 20).

Here's what I'm unsure about. The model above will allow me to test my main hypothesis. But, one thing I'd also like to do is compare the mean ratings *across groups* and assess whether groups with higher mean ratings for IV1 tend to have higher mean ratings for Statement(a), and lower mean ratings for Statement(b). It'll be easy enough to plot the mean ratings for each group with respect to IV1, Statement(a), and Statement(b). But to observe the trend just described, do I need to run an additional test, or can I just look at the coefficients for Group?

Apologies if this is conceptually confused! I'm a mixed models newbie. Any feedback on whether I've specified the mixed model correctly would also be great.